# Why is the Runge Kutta solver excluding the damping coefficient?

Tags: python, vibration, runge-kutta

Good day. I wrote a code to use Runge-Kutta solver to analyse the vibration movement of 3 DOF suspension setup only in the vertical direction. I don't know why but the solver doesn't include the effect of damping in the result.

For background:

1. ) the force input is coded to simulate a bump in the road (Road displacement `x` tire stiffness).
2. ) I am using at first dummy nr's for the force as want to debug the solver first. Road force generator works fine.
3. ) the first equation setup is of the body movement

   `M*Z''+C_s*Z'+K_s*Z=C_s Z'_u+K_s*Z_u`

   and second equation is the tire movement

   `m*Z''_u+C_s*Z'_u+(K_s+K_t)*Z=C_s Z'+K_s Z+K_t Z_r`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#variables
Ks = 200
Kt = 1000
Cs = 0.5
M = 120
m = 20

Road_Amp = 1
Road_freq = 2

Hz_read = 1000
delta_t = 1/Hz_read

time_end = 10

time = np.linspace(0,time_end,time_end*Hz_read)

#force from road
def road_force(Ktire,Amp,freq,time_F,time_start_F,time_end_F,one_bump):
    F = np.array([0.0,0.0])
    if one_bump:
        time_end_F = time_start_F + np.pi/freq
    if (time_F >= time_start_F) and (time_F <= time_end_F):
        Disp = Amp * np.cos(freq*time_F - np.pi/2)
    else:
        Disp = 0.0
    F[0]= Disp * Kt
    return F


def G(Y,time_function,force):
    eq1 = inv_A.dot(C.dot(Y[1])-B.dot(Y[0])) #equation for the body
    eq2 = inv_D.dot(H.dot(Y[0]) + force-E.dot(Y[1])) #equation for the wheel
    return np.array([eq1,eq2])


def RK4_step(Y,time_RK,dt,force_RK):
    k1 = dt * G(Y,time_RK,force_RK)
    k2 = dt * G(Y + 0.5*k1,time_RK + 0.5*dt,force_RK)
    k3 = dt * G(Y + 0.5*k2,time_RK + 0.5*dt,force_RK)
    k4 = dt * G(Y + k3,time_RK + dt,force_RK)
    
    return (k1 + k2*2 + k3*2 + k4)/6
  
      
#initial state
Y = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])

A = np.array([[M,0],[0,1]])
B = np.array([[Cs,Ks],[-1,0]])
C = np.array([[Cs,Ks],[0,0]])
D = np.array([[m,0],[0,1]])
E = np.array([[Cs,(Ks+Kt)],[-1,0]])
H = np.array([[Cs,Ks],[0,0]])
inv_A = inv(A)
inv_D = inv(D)

#solution
for t in time:
    Force = road_force(Kt,Road_Amp,Road_freq,t,0,5,True) 
    Y = Y + RK4_step(Y,t,delta_t,Force)
```

I have changed the damping coefficient but nothing changes in the graphs and still oscillates as if there is no damping. Please help

Comment: Making the force term piecewise constant over each step reduces the order of the method from 4 to 1. Having jumps in the force has the same effect on the global error, only that their influence appears as randomly. You are using Python 3?

Comment: Yes, I am using python 3. Is there another way I can simulate a bump displacement for the road input?

Comment: Even after removing the force and only using initial conditions, the damping is still not being considered in the equation. Is there another way which the equation can be coded and constrained to where it will consider the damping coefficient?

Comment: Your state is a matrix. Are you sure that the derivatives matrix is constructed the correct way, with `eq1, eq2` as the rows of the returned matrix? If you want them to be the columns, you need to transpose this, `return np.array([eq1,eq2]).T`.